# MYSQL Combine results of multiple subqueries

Tags: mysql

I need to combine the results of the following queries. I need to have the total messages processed internal and external together. Let me explain the queries and the data for them

Sample Data:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
| deviceCustomString2 | destinationUserName | deviceHostName | deviceProduct | sourceUserName |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
| <FD54>              | test@dmroot.net     | gemslab385mb   | Test Server   | Exchange       |
| <FX54>              | test@dmroot.net     | gemslabcht     | Test Server   | Exchange       |
| <FZ54>              | test2@yahoo.com     | gemslab385mb   | Test Server   | External       |
| <FA54>              | test@dmroot.net     | gemslab385mb   | Test Server   | Exchange       |
| <FD54>              | test@dmroot.net     | gemslab385mb   | Test Server   | Exchange       |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+
```

Query 1:

```
SELECT 
LEFT((LOWER(SUBSTRING_INDEX(b.deviceHostName,'.',1))),(LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(b.deviceHostName,'.',1))-2)) as "Device_Group",
COUNT(b.deviceCustomString2) as "Total_Messages_Processed_EXTERNAL"
FROM 
      ( SELECT                    
                   TEST2.deviceCustomString2,
                   TEST2.deviceHostName
         FROM
                   TEST2
         WHERE
                   TEST2.deviceProduct="Test Server"
         AND 
                   (TEST2.destinationUserName NOT LIKE '%dmroot.net%' 
                AND TEST2.destinationUserName NOT LIKE '%banco2%'
                AND TEST2.sourceUserName NOT LIKE '%Exchange%')
         GROUP BY
                   TEST2.deviceCustomString2,
                    TEST2.deviceHostName
                  ) as b
```

Query 1 Result:

```
+--------------+-----------------------------------+
| Device_Group | Total_Messages_Processed_EXTERNAL |
+--------------+-----------------------------------+
| gemslab385   |                                 1 |
+--------------+-----------------------------------+
```

Query2:

```
SELECT 
LEFT((LOWER(SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.deviceHostName,'.',1))),(LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.deviceHostName,'.',1))-2)) as "Device_Group",
    COUNT(a.deviceCustomString2) as "Total_Messages_Processed_INTERNAL"
FROM 
      ( SELECT                    
                   TEST2.deviceCustomString2,
                   TEST2.deviceHostName
         FROM
                   TEST2
         WHERE
                   TEST2.deviceProduct="Test Server"
     AND 
                   (
                    TEST2.destinationUserName LIKE '%dmroot.net%' 
                OR TEST2.sourceUserName  LIKE '%Exchange%'
               )
         GROUP BY
                   TEST2.deviceCustomString2


                  ) as a

GROUP BY
Device_group
```

Query 2 Result:

```
+--------------+-----------------------------------+
| Device_Group | Total_Messages_Processed_INTERNAL |
+--------------+-----------------------------------+
| gemslab385   |                                 2 |
| gemslabc     |                                 1 |
+--------------+-----------------------------------+
```

Results from Both queries are fine and it removes the duplicated record.

Now when I add UNION ALL between the 2 queries I get this result

```
+--------------+-----------------------------------+
| Device_Group | Total_Messages_Processed_EXTERNAL |
+--------------+-----------------------------------+
| gemslab385   |                                 1 |
| gemslab385   |                                 2 |
| gemslabc     |                                 1 |
+--------------+-----------------------------------+
```

The totals are correct, but not displaying the TOTAL_MESSAGES_PROCESSED_INTERNAL. how do I make it output something like this:

```
+--------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| Device_Group | Total_Messages_Processed_INTERNAL | Total_Messages_Processed_EXTERNAL | 
+--------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| gemslab385   |                                 2 |                                 1 |
| gemslabc     |                                 1 |                                   | 
+--------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Marcello

Comment: Just try UNION DISTINCT instead of UNION ALL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare the list in the inner select, count groups conditionally in the outer select.

```
SELECT

  LEFT(LOWER(t.deviceGroup), LENGTH(t.deviceGroup) - 2) AS "Device_Group",

  COUNT(DISTINCT
    CASE
      WHEN t.destinationUserName NOT LIKE '%dmroot.net%' AND
           t.destinationUserName NOT LIKE '%banco2%' AND
           t.sourceUserName NOT LIKE '%Exchange%'
      THEN CONCAT(t.deviceCustomString2, '.', t.deviceHostName)
    END) AS "Total_Messages_Processed_EXTERNAL",

  COUNT(DISTINCT
    CASE
      WHEN t.destinationUserName LIKE '%dmroot.net%' OR
           t.sourceUserName LIKE '%Exchange%'
      THEN CONCAT(t.deviceCustomString2, '.', t.deviceHostName)
    END) AS "Total_Messages_Processed_INTERNAL"

FROM (
  SELECT
    deviceCustomString2,
    deviceHostName,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.deviceHostName, '.', 1) AS deviceGroup,
    destinationUserName,
    sourceUserName
  FROM TEST2
  WHERE deviceProduct="Test Server"
) AS t

GROUP BY Device_Group
```

When counting groups, I'm using this construct: `CONCAT(t.deviceCustomString2, '.', t.deviceHostName)`. You know your data better, and so it may appear that the expression can be changed simply to `t.deviceCustomString2` or `t.deviceHostName`, only mind the `DISTINCT` keyword.

Additionally, to help the calculations slightly, I moved `SUBSTRING_INDEX(a.deviceHostName, '.', 1)` to the inner SELECT, so it doesn't evaluate twice.

Answer (score 0):

What you want isn't really a union, it's just a normal join. Here's an example but I haven't tested the syntax so it might need some tweaks before it works:

```
(SELECT 
LEFT((LOWER(SUBSTRING_INDEX(b.deviceHostName,'.',1))),(LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(b.deviceHostName,'.',1))-2)) as "Device_Group",
COUNT(b.deviceCustomString2) as "Total_Messages_Processed_EXTERNAL", COUNT(a.deviceCustomString2) as "Total_Messages_Processed_INTERNAL"
FROM 
      ( SELECT                    
                   TEST2.deviceCustomString2,
                   TEST2.deviceHostName
         FROM
                   TEST2
         WHERE
                   TEST2.deviceProduct="Test Server"
         AND 
                   (TEST2.destinationUserName NOT LIKE '%dmroot.net%' 
                AND TEST2.destinationUserName NOT LIKE '%banco2%'
                AND TEST2.sourceUserName NOT LIKE '%Exchange%')
         GROUP BY
                   TEST2.deviceCustomString2,
                    TEST2.deviceHostName
                  ) as b LEFT JOIN 
      ( SELECT                    
                   TEST2.deviceCustomString2,
                   TEST2.deviceHostName
         FROM
                   TEST2
         WHERE
                   TEST2.deviceProduct="Test Server"
     AND 
                   (
                    TEST2.destinationUserName LIKE '%dmroot.net%' 
                OR TEST2.sourceUserName  LIKE '%Exchange%'
               )
         GROUP BY
                   TEST2.deviceCustomString2


                  ) as a ON a.deviceCustomString2 = b.deviceCustomString2 AND a.deviceHostName = b.deviceHostName

GROUP BY
Device_group
```

Comment: Thanks. I could not get the JOIN to work properly. The "ON a.deviceCustomString2 = b.deviceCustomString2 AND a.deviceHostName = b.deviceHostName" seems to be the problem as the x.deviceHostName is not available if there are no message INTERNAL or EXTERNAL from each one of the subqueries.